# Pig Latin string iteration, multiple word

Tags: c++

I'm reading a book for C++ and one of the exercises to create a pig latin translator. I have figured out all the necessary steps to translate a single word. Now I am having a lot of trouble with making a function for handling multi-word strings.

Basically I need help with the sort of standard idiom for iterating through each word of a string and performing an action on each word.

The function I have so far is sloppy at best and I am just stuck.

```
string sentenceToPigLatin(string str) {
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.at(i);
        if (ch == ' ') {
            result += toPigLatin(str.substr(0, i));
            str = str.substr(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can assume toPigLatin() performs the correct procedure for a word not containing whitespace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c - you'll get lots of ideas from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the whole string in a [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and use extraction operator to get out a single word:

```
#include <sstream>  // for stringstreams

string sentenceToPigLatin(const string& str)
{ 
    istringstream stream(str);
    ostringstream result;
    string temp;
    while (stream >> temp)
            result << toPigLatin(temp) << ' ';
    return result.str();
}
```

Another way is to use [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) together with [stream iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator):

```
#include <algorithm> // for transform
#include <iterator>  // for istream_iterator and ostream_iterator

string sentenceToPigLatin(const string& str)
{ 
    istringstream stream(str);
    ostringstream result;
    transform(istream_iterator<string>(stream),
              istream_iterator<string>(),
              ostream_iterator<string>(result, " "),
              toPigLatin);
    return result.str();
}
```

Comment: is the & for pass by reference? im new to c++ and have been confused by the (const and the &) in the parameters. & is pass by ref, right? but the const is so that it can't be changed?

Comment: Correct. You avoid potentialy expensive copies this way. Stringstream will make a copy of the string in it's own buffer, anyway.